# 2 column footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I am unable to use the `\dblfnote` package. When I combine it with the `\footmisc` package it does not interact well. Is there another package or way to get the same result? I have created two columns footnotes, but the formatting is not correct. The number is on the inside, but I would prefer it to be on the outside. I have attached a MWE and two pictures: the desired output and the current output.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,14pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{zref-abspage}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[perpage,abovefloats,side]{footmisc}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{extramarks}

\setmainlanguage{syriac}
\setmainfont[BoldFont={DejaVu Serif Bold}]{Serto Antioch Bible}

% % Make Counters for Chapters and Verses
\newcounter{mychapter}
\newcounter{bibver}
\setcounter{mychapter}{0}
\setcounter{bibver}{0}

% % Make Bible Chapter and Verses
\newcommand{\mychaptermark}{}
\newcommand{\bibvermark}{}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{mychapter}% Increment the mychapter counter
  \renewcommand{\mychaptermark}{#1}%
  %\chaptermark{#1 : \bibvermark}% Include the verse number in the chaptermark
  \markboth{#1}{#1}
  \needspace{3\baselineskip}% Minimum space required before the text
  \vspace{.5cm}
  {\centering\Large\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\space\themychapter\space}}% Center the chapter title with bold chapter number
}
\newcommand{\bibver}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{bibver}% Increment the bibver counter
  \extramarks{#1}{#1}% Set both left and right marks to #1
  \textsuperscript{\textbf{#1 }}~%
}


% % Make Book Title in English and Syriac
\newcommand{\englishtitle}[1]{\centering\LR{#1}}
\newcommand{\syriactitle}[1]{\centering{#1}}

% Footnotes

% \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\small} % Reduce the font size of footnotes
% \interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 
\twocolumnfootnotes
% \let\oldfootnote\footnote
% \renewcommand{\footnote}[1]{\oldfootnote{~#1}}

\newcommand{\mymarks}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\leftmark}{\rightmark}}
{} % if equal
{\leftmark--\rightmark}} % if not equal 

% % Set the headheight and potentially adjust topmargin
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt} % Adjust this value as needed
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.5pt} % Adjust this value as needed

% % Customize header using fancyhdr
% % \pagestyle{fancy}
% % \fancyhead{} % Clear previous header settings
% % \fancyhead[CO]{\englishtitle}
% % \fancyhead[CE]{ܐܓܪܬܐ ܕܝܘܚܢܢ ܫܠܝܚܐ}
% % \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\leftmark:\lastleftxmark –– \rightmark:\firstrightxmark} % Right on odd pages, Left on even pages



\begin{document}

\bibver{1}\RL{ܡܣܰܒ݁ܪܻܝܢܰܢ ܠܟ݂ܽܘܢ܆ ܠܗܰܘ ܕܻ݁ܐܝܬ݂ܱܘܗ̄ܝ ܗ̄ܘܳܐ ܡܶܢ ܒ݁ܪܻܫܺܝܬ݂܇
ܗܰܘ ܕܱ݁ܫܡܰܥܢ ܘܰܚܙܰܝܢܳܝܗ̄ܝ ܒ݁ܥܰܝ̈ܢܰܝܢ܂ ܚܙܰܝܢ ܘܓ݂ܰܫܢ}\footnote{ܓܱ݁ܫ­-- perf. 1cp:
  touch, explore} \RL{ܒܻ݁ܐܝ̈ܕ݂ܰܝܢ܆ ܗܰܘ ܕܻ݁ܐܝܬ݂ܱܘܗ̄ܝ ܡܶܠܬ݂ܴܐ
ܕ݁ܚܰܝܷ̈ܐ܂\bibver{2}ܘܚܰܝܷ̈ܐ ܐܷܬ݂ܓ݁ܠܻܝܘ}\footnote{\RL{ܓܠܴܐ} ­--
  Ethpeal, perf. 3mp: to reveal, to manifest}\RL{܂ ܘܰܚܙܰܝܢ ܘܣܳܗܕܻ݁ܝܢܰܢ܂
ܘܡܰܟ݂ܪܙܺܝܢܰܢ}\footnote{\RL{ܟܪܙ} ­-- Aphel, ptcp. mp: to preach, to declare}
\RL{ܠܟ݂ܽܘܢ ܚܰܝܷ̈ܐ ܕܱ݁ܠܥܳܠܱܡ܇ ܗܳܢܽܘܢ ܕܻ݁ܐܝܬ݂ܱܝܗܽܘܢ ܗ̄ܘܰܘ ܠܘܳܬ݂ ܐܱܒ݂ܳܐ܂ ܘܶܐܬ݂ܓ݁ܠܻܝܘ}\footnote{\RL{ܓܠܴܐ}
  ­-- Ethpeal, perf. 3mp: to reveal, to manifest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you recognize the column "Related" to the right?, Like https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185183/three-column-layout-with-three-column-footnotes?rq=1 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261319/two-column-footnotes-plain-tex?rq=1 ?